# Delete specific name ranges using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array with few items, each item represents a name range. i am trying to write a code to delete the named ranges present ONLY in that array. Example:
[Arr1]={Fruits,Vegetables,friends,Classes}

I want to delete all the name ranges by the name of elements present in Arr1. Arr1 can have different elements at different points in time.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to delete named ranges entirely or just remove names?

Comment: Remove name ranges entirely

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
    Dim all_names, n
    all_names = Array("Fruits", "Vegetables", "friends", "Classes")
    For Each n In all_names
        Names(n).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should differentiate between the scope of the names to be deleted. It should also take account of the possibility that the name doesn't exist. Finally, since your array is intended to have different content it can't be specified in the executing procedure. Therefore my code below has a calling procedure to specify the array and scope, and an executing procedure which doesn't crash out when a name isn't found.

```
Sub CallDeleteNamedRanges()

    Dim Scope As Object
    Dim Arr() As String

    Set Scope = ThisWorkbook
'    ' you can specify a workbook, a worksheet, a table etc.
'    ' For example:-
'    Set Scope = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Arr = Split("Fruits,Vegetables,Friends,Classes", ",")
    DeleteNamedRanges Arr, Scope
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteNamedRanges(Arr() As String, _
                              Scope As Object)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        ' an error will occur if the name doesn't exist
        On Error Resume Next
        Scope.Names(Arr(i)).Delete
    Next i
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```